# Have to reset $PATH on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows Linux Subsystem

Tags: path, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am new to Linux Subsystem. I am trying to use a package in miniconda. Now after installing miniconda in order for it to work you need add the path like  this:
`export PATH=~/miniconda/bin:$PATH`
I do this and the `conda` works. I exit the terminal and when I come back and look at my $PATH (using `echo $PATH`) I see is reset and I have to do it again. What should do for it to stick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set and export the PATH variable in your .bashrc file

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: thanks so much your solution worked for me! I did more digging it seems like a common issue with conda and its derivatives. it should be add that native python will not run if this line is added to .bashrc and instead the conda variant will run